# I don't see ImageSwitcher in Pallete (Android Studio 3.2)

Tags: android-studio

I don't know why not see ImageSwitcher.

[image: Palatee]

Comment: same problem occurred with me too. I had no choice but to write the code in xml rather than using pallet.